# Redirect to the new page from the Google App Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm developing the google documents add-ons. I want to develop functionality which redirects to the new url from the google docs page. Anyone implemented this type of functionality? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to automatically redirect a user using Google Apps Script. Your best option is to open a dialog or sidebar with a link or button that takes the user to the target URL.